# TYPO3 templates and changes the div id

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript

I have a Template in TYPO3 that i want to use to some pages, in here i have a DIV.

Is it possible depending on the page UID, to changes the DIV ID. its the only div thats changes content/image, and im looking to put this DIV inside my main.html template.

so if

```
UID = 2 <div id="topbanner_about"></div>
UID = 3 <div id="topbanner_drills"></div>
```

and so on....
Can i do this, and can i do it in TS (Typo Script) or how can i do this, so i dont need to make 5 templates.

Comment: You might want to show at least the relevant parts of your TypoScript that are responsible for your templates. And in general, yes, this is surely possible with the help of markers that you can change depending on the page uid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by inserting a marker in your template. It would look somehow like this:

In the template:

```
[...]
<div id="topbanner_###ID_SUFFIX###"></div>
[...]
```

In the TypoScript, where the template is inserted:

```
10 = TEMPLATE
10 {
    template = FILE
    template.file = fileadmin/main.html

    marks {
        ID_SUFFIX = TEXT
        ID_SUFFIX {
            insertData = 1

            # This makes sure that the output is valid and prevents XSS attacks
            htmlSpecialChars = 1

            value = {page:uid}      # Use this to insert the page ID or
            value = {page:subtitle} # Use to insert subtitle of page
            ... # Same works for other fields of the page record.
        }
    }
}
```

If the fields provided by default pages are not enough, you could add another field to the page records. The best way to do that would be to build an extension that does it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution, if i use ressource and add an image and on the next page do the same just with another images, then in my main TS i add this code.

```
lib.imageElement = FILES
lib.imageElement {
  references {
    data = levelmedia:-1,slide
    listNum = 0
  }
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    10 = IMAGE
    10 {
      file.import.data = file:current:originalUid
      altText.data = file:current:title
    }
  }
}
```

It do the trick, then it shows a diffrent image in the top/header on every page.
But thx...